# Counterpart of hstack and vstack in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

What would be the correct counterpart of the `numpy` functions `hstack` and `vstack` in **Tensorflow**?

There is `tf.stack` and `tf.concat` in `Tensorflow`, but i don't know how to use them or use the correct `axis` value, to achieve the same behaviour in Tensorflow.

Comment: Look at the code of `hstack` and `vstack` to see what dimension adjustments they make.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the `tf.concat` with different `axis` argument to get the same result as with `hstack` or `vstack`:

```
arr1 = np.random.random((2,3))
arr2 = np.random.random((2,3))
arr1
array([[0.72315241, 0.9374959 , 0.18808236],
       [0.74153715, 0.85361367, 0.13258545]])

arr2
array([[0.80159933, 0.8123236 , 0.80555496],
       [0.82570606, 0.4092662 , 0.69123989]])

np.hstack([arr1, arr2])
array([[0.72315241, 0.9374959 , 0.18808236, 0.80159933, 0.8123236 ,
        0.80555496],
       [0.74153715, 0.85361367, 0.13258545, 0.82570606, 0.4092662 ,
        0.69123989]])

np.hstack([arr1, arr2]).shape
(2, 6)

np.vstack([arr1, arr2])
array([[0.72315241, 0.9374959 , 0.18808236],
       [0.74153715, 0.85361367, 0.13258545],
       [0.80159933, 0.8123236 , 0.80555496],
       [0.82570606, 0.4092662 , 0.69123989]])

np.vstack([arr1, arr2]).shape
(4, 3)

t1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(arr1)
t2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(arr2)


tf.concat([t1, t2], axis=1)

<tf.Tensor: id=9, shape=(2, 6), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[0.72315241, 0.9374959 , 0.18808236, 0.80159933, 0.8123236 ,
        0.80555496],
       [0.74153715, 0.85361367, 0.13258545, 0.82570606, 0.4092662 ,
        0.69123989]])>

tf.concat([t1, t2], axis=1).shape.as_list()
[2, 6]

tf.concat([t1, t2], axis=0)

<tf.Tensor: id=19, shape=(4, 3), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[0.72315241, 0.9374959 , 0.18808236],
       [0.74153715, 0.85361367, 0.13258545],
       [0.80159933, 0.8123236 , 0.80555496],
       [0.82570606, 0.4092662 , 0.69123989]])>

tf.concat([t1, t2], axis=0).shape.as_list()
[4, 3]
```

You should use `tf.stack` only if you want to concatenate tensors [along a new axis](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat):

```
tf.stack([t1, t2]).shape.as_list()
[2, 2, 3]
```

In other words, `tf.stack` creates a new dimension and stacks the tensors along in.